# Pointer Sharing Idiom

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I cannot figure a way to do this in the general case. Say that I have 2 classes and they maintain pointers to each other:

```
class first {
    unique_ptr<second> p2;
public:
    first() : p2(this) {}
};

class second {
    first* p1;
public:
    second(first* arg) : p1(arg) {}
};
```

This all works fine and dandy, but what I really want is to use a `shared_ptr` as a part of `second` because `second` objects may also be created independently of `first`. They will just be passed a pointer to a `first` on construction, but they won't know if it's gone.

I can't just make `second::p1` a `shared_ptr` because I wouldn't know how to pass in `this` from `first::first()`.

Is there an idiom that can help me handle this?

Comment: `std::enabled_shared_from_this<T>` might be what you're looking for. It probably isn't safe to use in the constructor though.

Comment: You simply can't safely do this. There is no guarantee inside first that this is even dynamically allocated!

Comment: I guess std::weak_ptr was created to solve things like that

Comment: @SergeyA That may be the correct answer then. Not the answer that I wanted, but hey, a correct answer is a correct answer.

Comment: @Amadeus [`weak_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) looks like exactly what I want. I'm just not understanding how it can determine if the object has been destroyed?

Comment: @Kevin It looks like [it's recommended](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) that `enable_shared_from_this<first>` be inherited from by `first`. Which is weird. Seems like there is a bad smell there somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with the caveat that you can then only create instances on the heap. Using `std::shared_from_this` would be a nice solution but it can only be called once a `std::shared_ptr` to the object exists which is not possible until the constructor has finished, even when using `std::make_shared` and a `std::bad_weak_ptr` exception is thrown.

Instead we ensure that the only way to create an instance of this class is through a static function which does the necessary setup.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <memory>

class second;

class first {
    struct Unconstructable {};
    std::unique_ptr<second> p2;
public:
    first(Unconstructable) : p2() {}
    static std::shared_ptr<first> create() { 
        Unconstructable u;
        auto f = std::make_shared<first>(u);
        f->p2 = std::make_unique<second>(f);
        return f;
    }
};

class second {
    std::shared_ptr<first> p1;
public:
    second(std::shared_ptr<first> arg) : p1(arg) {}
};

int main()
{
    auto f = first::create();
}
```

**Edit**: The use of `Unconstructable` isn't really necessary but is required for the use of `std::make_unique`. If I were to simple make the constructor private then `std::make_unique` would fail to compile even if I made it a `friend` function since the implementation uses internal helper functions. Having a private `struct` as a constructor argument is a way to bypass this while still preventing construction from happening outside of the class itself.

Comment: Interesting, you're doing something like a factory idiom there... Seems like you could also just make `first::first()` private in this case couldn't you?

Comment: @JonathanMee Ah, that was so that `std::make_shared` would work, I'll add an explanation.

Comment: You do not have to make `first::first()` private. Defining custom constructor inhibits default constructor creation anyway. But first::first(unconstructible) has to remain public - required by `make_shared`.

Comment: @SergeyA You can't use `make_shared` but you can assuredly construct a `shared_ptr` even if the default constructor is private: `shared_ptr<first> f {new first };` [[Live Example](http://ideone.com/Ldk1Ku)] I like this approach much better cause it saves us from all the unnecessary struct definition and creation, and it's readily evident to people who look at the class what's going on.

Comment: @sjdowling Seems like moving would be bad. The `first` object is now required to continue to exist as long as a referencing `second` object exists. The hangup, is how a `second` could be created independently of a `first` at all?

Answer (score 0):

Copying from my comments as OP indicated this is an answer he is OK with.

Unfortunately, there is no safe way of doing so - for the simple matter of constructor not having a slightest idea how an object was allocated. What if it was not allocated dynamically at all?

`enable_shared_from_this`, as indicated in another comment, is not a solution either - it just allows to get a `shared_ptr` from a `weak_ptr` hidden inside the class. However, this is only safe as long as there is at least one `shared_ptr` already created and holding the lock - and again, this is not something which can be ensured from the constructor.

Comment: Can't you ensure it by making all constructors private and making a `friend` function which is a factory or creator for the class?  Even friending `std::make_shared` might work.

Comment: Friending std::make_shared will certainly not work. The 'unconstructible' idiom above works, but I generaly do not like classess that make statements about how they are created.

Comment: @SergeyA Could we perhaps maintain a `first::shared_ptr<first>` that was just reset in `first::~first()`? Thereby making `enable_shared_from_this` possible?